# Why is my PlaneGeometry not receiving a shadow?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using three.js to create a scene that has a model on it.  I have a plane on which the model sits, and a spotlight shining on the model.

The model is made up of a number of different objects.  All of the objects are set to receive and cast shadows.  Shadows are being cast on the model itself from other areas of the model.

The plane, however, won't receive shadows.  I'm unsure why.

I have adjusted the `spotLight.shadowCameraNear` and `spotLight.shadowCameraFar` properties to ensure both the model and plane are within the shadow area.  Still nothing.

Below is a screenshot of the model with the spotlight visible.
[image: Plane, spotlight and model]

I have the shadowmap enabled and set to the soft maps:

```
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true; // Shadow map enabled
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
```

My code is as follows:

```
<script>

    if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

    var container, stats, controls;
    var camera, scene, renderer, sceneAnimationClip ;

    var clock = new THREE.Clock();

    var mixers = [];
    var globalObjects = [];         

    init();

    function init() {

        var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

        container = document.createElement( 'div' );
        document.body.appendChild( container );

        // Scene
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xffffff, 50, 100 );

        // Camera
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, (window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight), 1, 10000 );
        camera.position.x = 1000;
        camera.position.y = 50;
        camera.position.z = 1500;
        scene.add( camera );

        // LIGHTS
        var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff,1 );
        spotLight.position.set( 5, 5, 6 );

        spotLight.castShadow = true;

        spotLight.target.position.set(-1, 0, 2 );
        spotLight.shadowDarkness = 0.5;             
        spotLight.shadowCameraNear = 4; 
        spotLight.shadowCameraFar = 25;

        scene.add( spotLight );

        // Camera helper for spotlight
        var helper = new THREE.CameraHelper( spotLight.shadow.camera );
        scene.add( helper );

        // ground
        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 30, 30 );
        geometry.receiveShadow = true;
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xcccccc, side: THREE.DoubleSide} );
        material.receiveShadow = true;
        var floor = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        floor.receiveShadow = true;
        floor.position.y = -1;
        floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
        scene.add( floor );

        // stats
        stats = new Stats();
        container.appendChild( stats.dom );

        // model
        var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
        manager.onProgress = function( item, loaded, total ) {
            console.log( item, loaded, total );
        };

        // BEGIN Clara.io JSON loader code
        var i = 0;
        var objectLoader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
        objectLoader.load("final-master-20170426.json", function ( object ) {

            var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

            object.traverse( function ( child )
            {
                if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { 
                    var material = child.material.clone();

                    material.shininess = 0;
                    material.wireframe = false;
                    material.normalScale = new THREE.Vector2( 1, 1 );

                    /* Roof Glass */
                    if(child.name == 'Roof_Glass') {
                        material.shininess = 100;
                        material.alphaMap = grayscale;
                        material.transparent = true;
                    }

                    // Beading
                    if(child.name.endsWith('_Beading')) {
                        material.color.setHex( 0x1e1e1e );
                        material.shininess = 100;
                    }

                    /* Pillars */
                    if(
                        child.name.indexOf('Pillar') == 0 ||
                        child.name == 'Main_Frame' || 
                        child.name == 'Main_Cross_Supports' ||
                        child.name == 'roof_batons' ||
                        child.name == 'Roof_Flashings'                              
                    ) {
                        material.color.setHex( 0x1e1e1e );
                        material.shininess = 100;
                    }

                    /* Lamps */
                    if(child.name.indexOf('Lamp') == 0) {
                        material.color.setHex( 0x1e1e1e );
                        material.shininess = 100;
                    }
                    // Set shadows for everything
                    material.castShadow = true;
                    material.receiveShadow = true;

                    child.material = material;

                    material = undefined;

                    globalObjects[child.name] = child;

                    console.log(child);
                }
            });
            object.position.y = -1;
            object.position.x = 0;

            scene.add( object );
            scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0xffffff, 50, 100 );

            i++;
        } );
        // END Clara.io JSON loader code

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            'antialias': true   
        });
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color );

        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        renderer.gammaInput = true;
        renderer.gammaOutput = true;
        renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true; // Shadow map enabled
        renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

        // controls, camera
        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
        controls.target.set( 0, 0, 0 );
        controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.5;
        camera.position.set( 8, 3, 10 );
        controls.update();

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        animate();

    }

    function onWindowResize() {

        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    }

    //

    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        stats.update();
        render();

    }

    function render() {

        var delta = 0.75 * clock.getDelta();
        camera.lookAt( scene.position );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed by using a `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial` instead of a `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial`.